# Google Appengine CRON task with spring velocityengineutil

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, velocity

I am trying to write a cron task in app engine for sending emails by calling mergetemplatewithstring in spring velocityengineutils.

Unfortunately it does not throw any exception but the mail is never sent. Anyone has any pointers?

Comment: Are you using App Engine's support for running [cron jobs (scheduled tasks)](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing similar issues. My Cron servlet was triggered and logging indicates that it fails when the call to mergeTemplateWithStrings is called. In my case VelocityEngine was null.

I am sure that some of the java class in your code is not initialized. Cross check your code and it should work once you ensure all classes are initialized.